# How can I use "nu install ..." to install nhibernate 3 alpha?

Tags: .net, ruby, nhibernate, rubygems

I've started using nu and I'm really starting to like the way it managed packages for .net libraries.

On this page: http://nu.wikispot.org/Current_Packages it says that you can install the nhibernate alpha version with nu, however I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Can anyone help me with the command I would need?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer now is to just use nuget and forget about trying to use nu.